# Pushing data to an multidimensional array JavaScript with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this JS [calendar library](https://github.com/rykdesjardins/js-calendar), which I wanna fill up with dates from my MySQL database.

This is looking like this:

```
    <script>

    var today = new Date();
    var matrix = {};
    var tmp;

    ';

    while($erg_termin = $res_termin_jahr -> fetch())
    {
        echo '
        matrix['.$erg_termin->termin_beginn_jahr.'] = {};
        ';
    }


    while($erg_termin = $res_termin_monat -> fetch())
    {
        echo '
        matrix['.$erg_termin->termin_beginn_jahr.']['.$erg_termin->termin_beginn_monat.'] = {};
        ';
    }

    while($erg_termin = $res_termin_tag -> fetch())
    {
        echo '
        matrix['.$erg_termin->termin_beginn_jahr.']['.$erg_termin->termin_beginn_monat.']['.$erg_termin->termin_beginn_tag.'] = {};
        ';
    }

    while($erg_termin = $res_termin -> fetch())
    {
        echo '
        matrix['.$erg_termin->termin_beginn_jahr.']['.$erg_termin->termin_beginn_monat.']['.$erg_termin->termin_beginn_tag.'].push({"displayname": "'.$erg_termin->termin_betreff.'"});
        ';
    }

    echo'

    console.log(matrix);


    </script>
```

My result I get in the sourcecode is:

```
    <script>

    var today = new Date();
    var matrix = {};
    var tmp;


        matrix[2018] = {};

        matrix[2018][02] = {};

        matrix[2018][02][05] = {};

        matrix[2018][02][08] = {};

        matrix[2018][02][11] = {};

        matrix[2018][02][12] = {};

        matrix[2018][02][15] = {};

        matrix[2018][02][18] = {};

        matrix[2018][02][19] = {};

        matrix[2018][02][05].push({"displayname": "Wöchentliche Wiederholung"});

        matrix[2018][02][08].push({"displayname": "Wöchentliche Wiederholung"});

        matrix[2018][02][11].push({"displayname": "Wöchentliche Wiederholung"});

        matrix[2018][02][12].push({"displayname": "Wöchentliche Wiederholung"});

        matrix[2018][02][15].push({"displayname": "Wöchentliche Wiederholung"});

        matrix[2018][02][18].push({"displayname": "Wöchentliche Wiederholung"});

        matrix[2018][02][19].push({"displayname": "Wöchentliche Wiederholung"});


    console.log(matrix);


    </script>
```

But here comes the problem. At the point of using the function `push` I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: matrix[2018][2][5].push is not a function`.

I guess the problem is that I want to push something to `matrix[2018][2][5]`. But I am not sure... How can I push values in JS to a multidimensional array?

And because there will be much more dates, I cannot simply create an array for each date. The code needs to be dynamically!

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Kind regards

Comment: Might be easier to build the big array naturally in php, then just output it with json_encode into a single js var... maybe. You have a bit going on there.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a direct answer, but hopefully, it'll help you get to where you need to be.

Hey Don,
Is there a specific reason why you're doing it like this?
It might be more prudent to simply use an ajax call and return JSON from your server and work with data that way. This way you can work with native/vanilla JS and you won't have to write PHP inside JS tags. Generally, this isn't recommended. and makes for convoluted, hard-to-read code.

I might be able to help out with this, are you using an MVC framework of any sort? It'll be easier to manipulate data on the frontend if you're returning well-structured data from your backend. Provide some sample PHP code!

Also, you may be getting the error if the object you're calling the push method on isn't an array. Try doing this to see what you're data type you're working with for that specific example:

```
console.log(typeof matrix[2018][2][5]);
```

See what you get.